# CSS, Flexbox sizing issue. Can someone please explain what is going on?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, carousel, netflix

Hi I am trying to make a netflix clone and have everything working the way I want but I am having an issue with the layout. No matter how I set the width of the div which contains the images they aren't changing. I've used the console and no rule seems to be in place that would prevent them from growing. I have set the images to 100% the width of their parent container but this makes them tiny.

I really struggle with CSS because there is no console telling you what is going wrong. If someone could take a look and help me understand I would greatly appreciate it. (Also, does anyone know how long it takes to stop feeling like an idiot when dealing with CSS?)

I have included code below.
the row__imgLarge is only applied on one particular row. This is having the same issue as the others.

```
<div className="row__images">
    {movies.map((movie) => (
      <div
        className={`row__imgContainer  ${
          isLargeRow ? "row__imgLarge" : ""
        }`}
        key={movie.id}
        onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
      >
        <img
          className="row__image"
          // {some movies don't have the a backdrop image, in these cases use poster instead}
          src={`${base_url}/${
            isLargeRow || !movie.backdrop_path
              ? movie.poster_path
              : movie.backdrop_path
          }`}
          alt={movie?.title || movie?.name || movie?.original_name}
        />
      </div>
    ))}

.row__images {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row__imgContainer {
  /* width: 15.8vw; */
  max-height: 40vh;
  width: 150vw;
  margin-right: 0.6vw;
}

.row__image {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transfrom 440ms;
}

.row__imgLarge {
  max-height: 40vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex items' (children of a flex container) widths are dictated by the flex container. You need to control them with flex properties. Look at [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#justify-content) on the container, and [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_flex-grow_property), [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_flex-shrink_property), and [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_flex-basis_property) on the items.

If you want the items at a specific unchanging width, for example, you'd set grow and shrink to 0, and basis to the desired width:

```css
.row_imgContainer {
  flex-grow: 0; /* don't grow */
  flex-shrink: 0; /* don't shrink */
  flex-basis: 200px; /* desired width */
}

.row_imgContainer {
  flex: 0 0 200px; /* shorthand, same as above */
}
```

If you just want a horizontally-scrolling row of images, set `overflow: auto` (or scroll) on the flex container and don't let the items shrink:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.container>* {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/200" />
  <img src="//placekitten.com/201" />
  <img src="//placekitten.com/200" />
  <img src="//placekitten.com/199" />
  <img src="//placekitten.com/200" />
  <img src="//placekitten.com/202" />
  <img src="//placekitten.com/204" />
</div>
```

Comment: Okay I see. So because flexbox is trying to fit all the images on the width of the page it is shrinking them to make this possible? Would you say then, that flexbox isn't the right approach for something like a carousel? If so, do you have a better suggestion (no worries if not, I know I should be doing this for myself)

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do it's hard to say one way or the other, but flexbox is incredibly versatile and dependable. I wouldn't necessarily abandon it without a good reason unless you had a better idea.

Comment: You can also apply `min-width` and `max-width` on flex items, which might be helpful in your case.

Comment: Okay, that you for your help and explanations. I'm new here so my upvotes aren't displayed but I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Updated my answer with a snippet showing a horizontally scrolling flex container.